# Nginx Regex Redirects %20 creating issues

Tags: regex, redirect, nginx

I'm trying to write some redirects on an nginx server using Regex. I've done it fine on a few there currently 1 which has an issue redirecting

https://www.regex101.com/r/iV6fD9/1

The link above shows the regex and what's it targeting however these should be redirecting to the home page when not at all.

```
location ~* (?:p|c)\/(?:CATEGORY_RosesFor%20Romance(?:\/.+|\.htm))$
{ rewrite ^ http://www.realflowers.co.uk$1 permanent; }
```

Comment: You can try `location ~ (([pc]/CATEGORY_RosesFor(?:%20|\+)?.*\.htm)) { .. }`

Comment: nginx normalize request, so `%20` becomes space (` `)

Comment: @hwnd That's done it. Would you be able to explain in an answer what I was missing? I'm still learning regex and would be good to learn from my mistakes.